# Как пользоваться интерфейсами и аннотацией @Override в Java?

Tags: java, аннотации

```
public class JavaApplication33 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        T t = new T();

        t.test();
        t.test2();
    }
}

public interface Test {

    void test();
    void test2(int a);

}

public class T implements Test {

    @Override
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @Override
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("test2");
    }
}
```

Можете подсказать пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Смотрю урок на ютубе по поводу интерфейсов, у автора все работает.

Сама ошибка:

> Error: java: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
>   Error: java: com.company.T is abstract; cannot be instantiated

И еще такой вопрос: где-то читал что методы интерфейсах нельзя оверрайдить — не знаю, или это я криво прочитал, но почему он именно это и делает?

Comment: Вместо `public void test2() {` должно быть `public void test2(int a) {`

Comment: спасибо) заработало)
а что там по поводу оверрайда методов интерфейса ? видимо, это я хреново прочитал?

Comment: В интерфейсе определён `test2` с целочисленным аргументом. Вы же *попытались* реализовать `test2` **без** аргументов. Такого варианта в интерфейсе не существовало, поэтому компилятор и выдал ошибку.

Comment: Не будь директивы `@Override`, java-файл собрался бы без предупреждений, но получившийся код работал бы неправильно.

Comment: Не так, `Существующую сигнатуру никто не определил, поэтому...`. А на сигнатуру без аргумента компилятору пофиг, это другой метод.

Comment: @Arhad не будь аннотации `@Override`, класс `T` всё равно бы не скомпилировался: _"error: T is not abstract and does not override abstract method test2(int) in Test"_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если почитать [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Override.html) для аннотации `@Override`, то увидим следующее:

> Indicates that a method declaration is intended to override a method declaration in a supertype. If a method is annotated with this annotation type compilers are required to generate an error message unless at least one of the following conditions hold:
>   - The method does override or implement a method declared in a supertype.
>   - The method has a signature that is override-equivalent to that of any public method declared in Object.

Т.е. эта аннотация нужна для того чтобы во время компиляции была осуществлена проверка, того **переопределен** ли данный метод или нет. Т.е. проверяется определен ли метод с подобной сигнатурой в классе родителе или интерфейсах, который реализует данный класс.

В вашем же случае, ошибка была в неправильной реализации интерфейса. Вы не корректно объявили сигнатуру для метод `test2` (в интерфейсе с параметрами, в классе нет). Аннотация, тут не причем.

Answer (score 3):

Аннотация `@Override` несет в себе двойной смысл:

1. Это прямое указание компилятору, что данный метод перекрывает метод объявленный в родительском классе и/или интерфейсе. Если допустим, не указана таковая аннотация, а сигнатура метода задана ошибочно, то компилятор не выдаст ошибку - что может привести к фатальным последствиям
2. Это напоминание разработчику, что данный метод появился не просто так, сам по себе, а перекрывает метод объявленный в суперклассе и/или интерфейсе - по крайней мере я, чаще всего использую аннотацию `@Override` именно в этом ключе.

Далее, до Java 6 - аннотация `@Override` работала только для методов суперкласса, начиная с Java 6 - аннотацию `@Override` можно (и нужно) применять и по отношению к методам декларированным в интерфейсе. Следы этого дуализма до сих пор остались в настройках некоторых IDE, где можно указывать scope применения аннотации `@Override`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]